# Play framework 2, routes and Json

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

I have a Python algorithm, which gets data online basically just text, and what I want to do now is sending this Python data (in Json format) into Play!.

A suggested idea was to do this :
Send the Json from Python to a route of the app for example :

```
GET     /api/localfeeds             controllers.Application.storeMessage(json: JsValue)
```

and then use :

```
public static Result storeMessage()
{
 // store the message
}
```

I'm doing this to learn to use java and the play framework. I'm pretty new to this so any information would be great.

Comment: Please remove the python tag. This is not python.

Comment: Voilà, removed @slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voilà!

Just send a JSON request to Play, [handle it easily as described in docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/JavaJsonRequests) and [return whatever](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/JavaActions) what you need.

Note: you won't be able to send JSON object as a GET param, so consider using POST request.

Comment: Thank you for your help @biesior So if I understand you, this wil work ? Here is my code, I don't understand how the json gets passed to  Java :/
http://pastebin.com/UA84MrQH

Comment: In general: yes, it'll work, anyway without concrete sample we can only give you a links to docs. Play handles JSON requests very well, it's also able to produce any response you need. Next time just ask about some more specific

Comment: Ok, I'll be more specific next time. It did not work but thanks anyways. :)